# MBtiles and mapbox js

Tags: mapbox

Currently I am doing graphical information system(GIS) web application  that allow user to upload their tileset eg mbtiles format to the system and view tileset using mapbox on browser. Now, I'am just use mapbox studio to upload tileset and take the sytle then copy to the code. My question is, how I want to upload mbtiles files to database and view in mapbox on browser without use mapbox studio

```js
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'accesstoken';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox style', // stylesheet mapbox style
        center: [100.2192660726069, 6.523753293936409], // starting position [lng, lat]
        // pitch: 60, // pitch in degrees
        // bearing: -60,
        zoom: 16 // starting zoom]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to view your map in the browser outside of Mapbox Studio, you can use the code snippet you have included above and create a container div `<div id="map"></div>` within the HTML of your page to display the map.

If you are asking how to programmatically upload your MBTiles file and add the tileset to an existing style without the use of Mapbox Studio, you will want to look into the Uploads or Tilesets API and Styles API.

For uploading the MBTiles file, you can work with the [Create an upload endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#create-an-upload) or the [Tilesets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilesets).

To then add the uploaded tileset to a style, you can use the [Update a style endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#update-a-style) or add it at runtime to the map using the [addLayer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addlayer) GL JS method.